# Get list of files from tfs changeset

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I need to get a list of changed files from chageset only and exclude all other junk.

I can get this information from the command tf changeset /i $(changesetnumber) but besides of List of files i have a lot of other information which I dont need for my purposes.

Or maybe someone can tell how to get this list of files from ccnet so I can send it to my msbuild.proj file via property.

Comment: Have you looked at the TFS API?

Answer (score 9):

You could use the TFS API to get the information you want. Here's some example C# code that will select the file names of all edited, added and deleted files

```cs
Uri serverUri = new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080/");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(changesetId);
var changedFiles = from change in changeset.Changes where
       (  (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Edit) == ChangeType.Edit
       || (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Add) == ChangeType.Add
       || (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Delete) == ChangeType.Delete)
     select change.Item.ServerItem;
```

I'm afraid I haven't used cc.net so can't advise on the best way to integrate this into ccnet, but you could compile it into a small utility or rewrite it in a scripting language (e.g. Powershell, IronPython)

Comment: I just wanted to take a moment to thank you for this.  You have no idea how instrumental this simple post has been in my creation of a custom merge tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CCNET's [Modification Writer Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Writer_Task). Put it to your CCNET configuration's `<prebuild>` section and process the generated file in your `<msbuild>` task:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Go" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Go">
    <XmlPeek
      XmlInputPath="$(CCNetArtifactDirectory)\modifications.xml"
      Query="/ArrayOfModification/Modification">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Modifications" />
    </XmlPeek>
    <MSBuild
      Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
      Properties="Modification=%(Modifications.Identity)"
      Targets="MessageModificationPath">
    </MSBuild>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="MessageModificationPath">
    <XmlPeek
      XmlContent="$(Modification)"
      Query="/Modification/FolderName/text()">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="FolderName" />
    </XmlPeek>
    <XmlPeek
      XmlContent="$(Modification)"
      Query="/Modification/FileName/text()">
      <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="FileName" />
    </XmlPeek>
    <Message Text="$(FolderName)$(FileName)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**Note**: I'm not really experienced in MSBuild so any advice on how to parse the XML output in a more elegant way is highly appreciated.

**Hint**: `<XmlPeek>` task requires .NET 4.0 MSBuild.