# move checked in files to another location in TFS2010

Tags: c#, android-activity, build

I am trying to create a custom build activity in C# that gets the list of files in the changesets from a build that was triggered by a check-in action in TFS 2010 and move those files from the SourcesDirectory to another location. The question is whether it is possible to retrieve the list of files that the user checks in to TFS 2010 that triggers a build so that I can loop through the files and move them to another location? So far, I have no luck.

Thanks much for any answers or help!

---

Thanks Loïc Faure-Lacroix for the comments. I guess my question was too broad so nobody answered my question. 
It took me a while to get to where I am now and here’s what I’ve managed to do so far. I got the idea from the following links to take the Changesets as a parameter for my custom activity. I also took the SourcesDirectory as a param which I could obtain from inside the “Run On Agent” sequence.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2010/09/02/custom-build-activity-for-tfs-2010-to-send-email-with-build-details-part-1.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codejunkie/archive/2010/09/15/custom-build-activity-for-tfs-2010-to-send-email-with-build-details-part-2.aspx

```
  [RequiredArgument]
  [Browsable(true)]
  public InArgument<IList<Changeset>> Changesets { get; set; }

  [RequiredArgument] // The source directory to copy the files from 
  public InArgument<string> SourcesDirectory { get; set; }
```

I then needed to loop through the changeset to get the list of items that were checked in to TFS. However, the items I got from the changeset contain the server path, namely, something like “$/MainProj/SubProj/contactus/contact.htm” so I needed a way similar to the ConvertWorkspaceItem activity that can convert the server path to the real local build path on the build server. Does anyone know how the ConvertWorkspaceItem actually work? The SourcesDirectory has the path similar to this (which I am not sure whether always has the same format or will change based on projects or how build server was configured.): C:\Builds\1\SubProj\Sources\contactus
Since I could not find a proper way to convert the paths so I used an ugly way of basic substring search and replacement… 
Once I looped through the changset, converted the server path to local source path, I was able to copy those files just checked in to TFS to another location such as a folder on our development server. 
Then I ran into one big obstacle. I got the access denied error from the build when I tested with creating a new folder with a few new files in it and checking those in to trigger the build. It seemed that some process or thread that created the new folder in TFS and checked the files in still lock the folder when the build started to run, which I assumed is another thread…    If the checked in files were in an existing folder, everything worked fine… Could anyone please share some insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what you've got so far? People aren't going to write a complete solution for you if there is any.

Comment: Sounds like you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311529/get-list-of-files-from-tfs-changeset