# Replacement for "Team Foundation PowerTools" TFPT GETCS command using TF VC commands

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc, tfs-power-tools, build-pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps Build/Release pipelines to duplicate PowerShell deployment scripts. Most of them use "Team Foundation PowerTools"  TFPT GETCS command. In order to use the pipelines, I need to use TF VC commands.

Does anyone know of a replacement for "Team Foundation PowerTools"  TFPT GETCS command

Comment: Hi AMissico, just checking to see if the information provided was helpful. We do not have any corresponding command in `tf.exe` at present. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I found the information earlier before posting. I had hoped someone developed a replacement in the few years after the last "Power Tools" were released for 2015.

Comment: Thanks for your update, AMissico. From 2017 there are no power tools any more. Cause most of the previous Power Tools have been integrated into TFS 2017. However, some tfpt command are not able to replace. There are also not any 3rd-party extension as a replacement. If my reply helped and you don't have any other concern on this question. Appreciate for marking it as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Comment: I am not going to mark it as answered, until someone posts a replacement or I write one.

Answer (score 0):

> **GetCS Command**
>
> Use the GetCS (Get Changeset) command to get the changes in a
>   particular changeset. Example: tfpt getcs /changeset:changesetnum

According to the description, this command is used to get just the files affected by a specific Changeset.

Unfortunately, we **do not have any corresponding command in `tf.exe`** version control command.

As we know that a changeset contains all the pending changes of one check in operation. And the change type may be None, Add, Edit, Encoding, Rename and etc. You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb170193(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for a better knowledge of ChangeType.

Instead of TFPT Getcs command, you could also use TFS API to achieve the similar thing.

A detail sample for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350130/5391065